# react-bootstrap modal disappears without setting showModal to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I have a login Modal, from react-bootstrap, that when I fill the username and password and click on login, it disappears without waiting to `showLoginModal` to be set to false. This is the component:

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
const AccountsMenu: React.FC = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const accounts = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.accounts)
    const location = useLocation()
    const getCurrentPath = () => location.pathname + encodeURIComponent(location.search)
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUserInfoAction())
    }, [dispatch])
    
    const registerPage = () => {
        navigate(ROUTES.REGISTER_ROUTE)
    }
    const [showLoginModal, setShowLoginModal] = useState(false)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('')
    const [usernameError, setUsernameError] = useState<string>('')
    const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState<string>('')
    const login = () => {
        // Check if username and password are not empty
        if (!username.trim()) {
            setUsernameError('Username cannot be empty.')
            return
        } else {
            setUsernameError('')
        }

        if (!password.trim()) {
            setPasswordError('Password cannot be empty.')
            return
        } else {
            setPasswordError('')
        }
        dispatch(actions.loginUser({ username: username, password: password }))
        setUsername('')
        setPassword('')
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (accounts.apiSuccess) {
            setShowLoginModal(false)
        }
    }, [accounts.apiSuccess])
    if (accounts.loading) return <li>Loading ...</li>
    return (
        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
            <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Account
            </a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                {accounts.userInfo.is_active ? (
                    <li>
                        <a href={'/b/logout?next=' + getCurrentPath()} className="dropdown-item">
                            Logout
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <li>
                            <a href={'/b/login?next=' + getCurrentPath()} className="dropdown-item">
                                Login
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onClick={() => registerPage()} className="dropdown-item">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onClick={() => setShowLoginModal(true)} className="dropdown-item">
                                Login modal
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </>
                )}
            </ul>
            <Modal show={showLoginModal} onHide={() => setShowLoginModal(false)} centered={true}>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center m-3">
                    <ErrorHandling error={accounts.error} loading={accounts.loading} />
                </div>
                <form className="p-4">
                    <div className="form-outline mb-4">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="username">
                            User name:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="username"
                            className={`form-control ${usernameError ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                setUsername(e.target.value)
                                setUsernameError('')
                            }}
                        />
                        {usernameError && <div className="invalid-feedback">{usernameError}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-outline mb-4">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">
                            password:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            className={`form-control ${passwordError ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                setPassword(e.target.value)
                                setPasswordError('')
                            }}
                        />
                        {passwordError && <div className="invalid-feedback">{passwordError}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-outline mt-5 text-center">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => login()}>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </Modal>
        </li>
    )
}
```

I have tried the following so far:

1. I have changed the login button type to 'button' instead of 'submit' to prevent the form from refreshing the page.
2. I tried using `div` tag instead of `form` tag, still it behaved the same.
3. I tried moving the login `button` outside the `form`, but still, the same behavior.

I searched for similar questions, but none addressed this issue.

UPDATE ON QUESTION:

I tried to comment out different parts of the login, and the part that is causing this is the `dispatch(actions.loginUser({ username: username, password: password }))` part. I am not sure how can I prevent this. Or if I can not, how can I solve this any other way.

Comment: The modal is controlled by the `showLoginModal` state, and there's an effect to disable the modal upon a truthy selected `accounts.apiSuccess` value. What is this `accounts.apiSuccess` value over time? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: It was related to the redux store, as I have guessed. So, I am going to include the answer completely. Thanks for the comment by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION I HAVE FOUND:

So, as I have guessed before, the problem was from this part:
`dispatch(actions.loginUser({ username: username, password: password }))`. In other words, when the redux store got changed, it caused the page to re-render. But if we want to put it more precisely, This was the part that was causing the page to re-render:

```
 if (accounts.loading) return <li>Loading ...</li>
```

So before, our redux store for account type was like this:

```
export interface AccountsStoreType {
    error: string | { [key: string]: string } | null
    loading: boolean
    userInfo: UserInfoType
    registerSuccess: boolean | null
}

export interface UserInfoType {
    username?: string
    first_name?: string
    last_name?: string
    email?: string
    is_active: boolean
    is_staff: boolean | null
}
```

We had one `loading` and one `error` key for all the stuff related to the user, like logging in, logging out, registering, and getting user info.

So, I tried separating the store:

```
export interface LoginType {
    loading: boolean
    success: boolean | null
    error: string | { [key: string]: string } | null
}
export interface RegisterType {
    loading: boolean
    success: boolean | null
    error: string | { [key: string]: string } | null
}
export interface LogoutType {
    loading: boolean
    success: boolean | null
    error: string | { [key: string]: string } | null
}
export interface UserInfoType {
    error: string | { [key: string]: string } | null
    loading: boolean
    username?: string
    first_name?: string
    last_name?: string
    email?: string
    is_active: boolean
    is_staff: boolean | null
    about_me?: string
    user_score?: number
    user_contributions?: UserContributionType[]
}
export interface AccountsStoreType {
    login: LoginType
    register: RegisterType
    logout: LogoutType
    userInfo: UserInfoType
}
```

After separating the types, that specific line that I pointed out in the beginning of this answer, got converted to this:

```
    if (accounts.userInfo.loading) return <li>Loading ...</li>
```

As you see, now it gets the `loading` from it's own related store, and registering does not have any affect on rendering this part.